# Let $f$ be the mapping from $S_n$ to the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$f$ is defined by
$$f(\delta)= 
\begin{cases}
    [0],& \text{if $\delta$ is an even permutation}\\\\
    [1], &  \text{if $\delta$ is an odd permutation}
\end{cases}$$

is $f$ an epiomorphism , i already proved that it is a homomorphism, but now $S_1$ is only an even permuation right ? and so it is not surjective for $S_1$ but if $n > 1$ then i guess it is an epimorphism , and of course it is not a monomorphims right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, but usually one doesn't worry about such corner cases.

Technically speaking $S_0$ and $S_1$ each have one element, which is an even permutation. In these cases the sign homomorphism is not surjective.

Also note that epimorphism is the same as surjective, but this is a non-trivial theorem of Otto Schreier.